# How to get Organisation Directory list from Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way we can get Directory of all users? `me/people` gives relevant users which is not a complete list of users. We need to access complete list of users for searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/users` endpoint seems to be what you're looking for. Documentation is at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list

For example, a call to `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` should return a paged list of all users in the tenant.
I also recommend you take a look at the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) that has samples for querying this endpoint.  You can view these by clicking the `show more samples` link.

[image]